# Kaltura HTML5 player in iOS and Android

Tags: kaltura

I am working in Kaltura gemini version to stream my videos. I want to play them in PC's and devices. I am able to play the videos in PC's but not able to play the videos in iOS and android devices like iPad and Tablets. I am getting the following error.

Unknown user_101 like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your localSettings.php file to point your kaltura server. By default it points to Kaltura.com, which is SAAS. But in your case it's not a SAAS right? So you have to replace all instances of kaltura.com to *yourKalturaServer.example.com* (for example). This will solve the problem.

The file is under the path of *yourKalturaServer.example.com*/html5/html5lib/version/localSettings.php

Hope this helps.